# Selenium WebDriver -- How can I know a certain line has executed successfully?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am testing a web application and my sample test case has three steps:

1. Enter Username
2. Enter Password
3. Click 'Login'

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
   driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
   driver.findElement(By.id("LoginButton")).click();
   ```

I need to generate a report which specifies which steps passed and which failed. Is there some mechanism by which I can know that each of those lines executed successfully? Does Selenium have some kind of inbuilt Activity/Event Listener?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'pass'? If the action it performed did what you expect it to do? Only *you* could know that. It's logic you'll need to put in place.

Answer (score 2):

If you want log all basic steps like click, navigate, on find element, etc

I recommend you add some event listener. You can use the class EventFiringWebDriver.

An example:

```
EventFiringWebDriver events = new EventFiringWebDriver(this._driver);   

events.Navigated += new EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs>(eventAfterNavigate);
```

and you can define the event handler as

```
private void eventAfterNavigate(object sender, WebDriverNavigationEventArgs e)
{
   Log("URL visited: " + e.Driver.Url);  // Call to your favourite log method
}
```

You can find more possible event handlers in the Webdriver API reference: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_Events_EventFiringWebDriver.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may use either Verify or Assert to be sure that something is present or absent on the page. Verify will return you Boolean and continue running while Assert on false will stop you test(s).

In this particular case you may verify that you typed username into element with id=username. So your code could look like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username); // this will enter username
assertEquals(selenium.getValue("id=username"), username); // this will check that text in your username field is 'username' (also you may use Assert.IsTrue)
```

As far as I know there is verifyTextPresent in Selenium 2 Webdriver, so you may use this:

```
try
{
assertEquals(selenium.getValue("id=username"), username); // put message into your log: success
}
catch (Exception)
{
// put message into your log: failed
}
```

I suggest to verify Button click but waiting for some notification that you logged in: e.g. text "Hello, {username}" might appear, or new element (absent before log in) might appear as well. So if this element is present - you are definitely logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if each step is successful, then I put some asserts (depending on your unit testing framework) to verify that the steps succeeded.

For example, to check that the username field actually received input, you could immediately verify that the username field has the text of whatever the username is that was typed in.

Some pseudo code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
element.sendKeys(username);
assertsEquals(username, element.text);
```

Likewise, to verify that a click was successful, you could check and assert that an element that is expected on the next page exists, which would then indicate that the login was successful.

Answer (score 0):

If Selenium dose not throw Exception then *lines are executed successfully*.

But question is how do you define success? I would check site that was loaded after click on LoginButton to be sure that behavior of web application is like you expect.